# Extjs4 combobox set value field and display fileld

Tags: forms, combobox, extjs4

I'm using Extjs4. I've to set combobox display field and value field in form load. setValue() not working for comboxes in form load. I'm using bellow code Please let me know whats wrong with my code.

```
quiz_edit_form.load({
    url: BASE_URL + 'courses/testing/getCourseTest/' + quiz_id,
    method: 'POST',
     success: function(form, action){
            var chap_name = action.result.data.test_chapter_combo;
            var less_name = action.result.data.test_lesson_combo;
            Ext.getCmp('test_chapter_combo1').setValue(chap_name);
            Ext.getCmp('test_lesson_combo1').setValue(less_name);
            }
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've recently had a similar issue with the combos. Ensure the `forceselection` attribute on the combo's are set to `false`, or it won't allow you to set any values that aren't in the store - and the store won't be loaded until a user clicks the trigger. If you do need to have the users only select options from the combo, set `forceselection: false`,  then `setValue` and `setRawValue`, then `forceselection: true`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: No. This is my combobox code {
                xtype: 'combobox', id: 'test_chapter_combo1',
                //hiddenName: 'test_linkchapter_val',
                displayField: 'chapter_name',
                valueField: 'chapter_id',
                fieldLabel: 'Select Chapter',
                allowBlank: false,
                blankText: 'Chapter is required',
                triggerAction: 'all',
                queryMode: 'remote',
                store: chapter_store,
                anchor: '60%',
                selectOnFocus: true
            }

Comment: Can you use something like Firebug to determine using `console.info()` to check the combo's definitely exist when you are trying to call the `setValue()`? Do they render ok and it's just `setValue()` that isn't working? Seems bizarre that there would be no errors.

Comment: i'm using Firebug, But there is no errors on the console window.

Comment: There may not be any errors, but do actually exist at the point you are calling the `setValue()`?

Answer (score 0):

The value you are trying to set must be present in the store bound to your combo. To get your values in the store you must have it autoloaded or load it way ahead of time - remember the store loads asynchronously.

Comment: That's not the case if `forceselection` is set to `false`.