# Binding an ExtJs combobox form field's selected item

Tags: asp.net-mvc, extjs

I've just started working with extjs 4 and I'm trying to use it alongside asp.net MVC 3. I'm having trouble setting up a typical form for editing a record where one of the fields uses a ComboBox. I cant seem to find an elegant way to bind the initial selected value to the value of a property on my model. Does anyone have any suggestions. I would think this should be simple to accomplish. Here's my form so far... Thanks in advance.

```
          {
            xtype: 'form',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'combobox',
                    fieldLabel: 'Group',
                    displayField: 'Name',
                    valueField: 'GroupId',
                    store: 'GroupStore',
                    allowBlank: false,
                    forceSelection: true,
                    editable: false,
                    queryMode: 'local'                       
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name: 'Description',
                    fieldLabel: 'Description'
                }
            ]
        }
```

Comment: Code seems fine. What's the problem?

Comment: Basically Im loading this form with a record selected from a grid. The model bound to the form has a GroupId and a Description. The combobox is bound to its own store "GroupStore" containing a collection of groups. When the form loads my combobox is filled with groups but no selected value set to my record's GroupId and my Description field is populated. I keep thinking its a timing issue with the asynch loading of the combobox store.

Comment: This is very possible. Load is async. You need first to load GroupStore and after that load model containing field in the combobox

Comment: Apparently this is a known issue in extjs as stated here http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?75751-OPEN-42-ComboBox-s-setValue-call-with-a-remotely-loaded-Store . It looks like it never got resolved and the only solution is to implement some hackish overrides. It seems like there has to be a cleaner, more standardized approach to this common scenario of a simple form based biz app.

Comment: I have posted a hacky workaround here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9327629/extjs4-combobox-set-value-field-and-display-fileld/9328802#9328802 which may help.